# Find the point where this function is not locally invertible

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y) = (x-y, xy)$. I have to find the points where $f$ is not locally invertible. The Jacobian is nonsingular at all points NOT of the form (x, -x), so by the inverse function theorem, $f$ is locally invertible at those points. Now, I know that at each point of the form $(x, -x)$ the function is not locally invertible, because every neighborhood of $(x,-x)$ contains points of the form $(x + t,-x + t)$ and $(x - t, -x - t)$ for some $t > 0$. But $f$ maps both of those points to the same point.

But one thing that is bothering me is that I thought I found an inverse for $f$. I set $f(x,y) = (x-y, xy) = (u,v)$. So $x -y  =u$ and $xy = v$. The first equation implies that $x = u + y$. Substituting this into the second equation gives $y^2 + yu - v = 0$. It's easy to check that the discriminant of this is non-negative, and thus it always have a solution. Solving gives $y = \frac{-u \pm \sqrt{u^2 + 4v}}{2}$, which means that $x = \frac{u \pm \sqrt{u^2 + 4v}}{2}$. If I let $g(u,v) = (\frac{u \pm \sqrt{u^2 + 4v}}{2}, \frac{-u \pm \sqrt{u^2 + 4v}}{2})$, then $(f \circ g)(u,v) = (u,v)$. So doesn't this mean that $g = f^{-1}$? But then it looks like I solved for a global inverse, which I just showed above it impossible. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: (edited) Your function $g$ contains some plus/minus ($\pm$) signs in its definition. Does $g$ really assign just one point to each point in its domain? Is it a function? Addition: Maybe this is like saying that for the non-invertible function $\phi(x)=x^2$ you have still found and inverse function $\psi(x)=\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I made a choice to take the "plus solution". It is an arbitrary choice, but $g$ is definitely a function, and when composed with $f$, it gives the identity.

Comment: Did you check both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$? Also, what set should be the domain of $g$ (the range of $f$)?

Comment: Ah, checking $g \circ f$ reveals the problems. I won't bore you with the details. Thanks! Quick question though: I was always under the impression that if $f \circ g$ was the identity map then $g \circ f$ was the identity as well? I thought I only had to check composition in one direction. Is there any time where checking one direction is good enough?

Comment: My example from the first comment where $\phi(x)=x^2$ is not invertible, but still has $\psi(x)=\sqrt{x}$ (I chose the sign arbitrarily). It seems that I should try with $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and then $\psi: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\phi\circ\psi$ (first take square root, then square) is really the identity, on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. But the other composition, $\psi\circ\phi$ (first square, then take square root) is _not_ the identity on the entire set $\mathbb{R}$. Actually $\psi\circ\phi$ is the absolute value function. Isn't this analogous to your example?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem with my function if we are trying to solve for a local inverse at a point on the line $y = -x$. This makes me wonder, under what conditions is a one-sided inverse also a two-sided inverse?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, I have deduced that the function is not locally invertible at $(x,y)$ if $y = -x$. I am now wondering, under which conditions is a one-sided inverse also a two-sided inverse?

Comment: @JonathanGafar I posted my comment without seeing your last comment!

Comment: @JonathanGafar The two sided inverse should be $$g(x, y) = (\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4y}}{2}, \frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4y}}{2}). $$ You should be able to figure out the conditions!